# "No matching function call" in constructor

Tags: c++, function, object, constructor, matching

This is the constructor declaration that I have in my "solver.h" file.

```
Solver(const Board &board_c, int max_moves_c);
```

When trying to compile I get the following error...

```
solver.cpp: In constructor 'Solver::Solver(const Board&, int)':
solver.cpp:6:55: error: no matching function for call to 'Board::Board()'
  Solver::Solver(const Board &board_c, int max_moves_c)
```

And then it lists the candidates which are the Board constructors.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I see no reason why I should be getting this error.

I am compiling with g++.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> error: no matching function for call to 'Board::Board()'

means that class `Board` is missing the deafault constructor. In the constructor of `Solver` you are probably doing something like:

```
Solver::Solver(const Board &board_c, int max_moves_c) {
    Board b; // <--- can not construct b because constructor is missing
    ...
}
```

so you either have to define the default constructor or invoke the appropriate constructor with some arguments.

> *"And then it lists the candidates which are the Board constructors."*

That's because compiler wants to help you so it lists possible constructors that are actually available (defined).